# "One reason for that is that.." alternatives

Tags: synonyms

I think using two "that" within 3 words does not sound nice.
Is there any alternative, and perhaps shorter, alternative for this construct?

Comment: One reason for that is because... People sometimes add a bit of wordiness while they are thinking, rather than leave a silence.

Comment: It's almost impossible to say anything about this without more context. Please provide one or more sentences prior to this, as well as the completion of the actual sentence. (The shortest possible phrasing is just *One reason is …*)

Comment: The first _that_ is referential and stressed, so would have an /æ/ vowel: /ðæt/. The second _that_ is a complementizer, unstressed, so would have a reduced /ə/ vowel: /ðət/. They're easy to tell apart (and pronounce together) so there should be no difficulty in writing. Remember, if you want readers to remember what you're writing, you have to make them ***hear*** it.

Comment: Simple way out?  Replace  ‘that’ for ‘this’.  If what it refers to is what has just been said, then why not leave out “for that” altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, you could condense it to "...one reason is that...", or "...one reason for that is...", or make it as simple as "because".